# Move a list item into another list Angular5

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, javascript-objects, angular5

Hello I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to move one object into another array of objects on click.

This is some of my code in the Typescript file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-roster-box",
  templateUrl: "./roster-box.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./roster-box.component.css"]
})
export class RosterBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  itemCount: number = 4;
  btnText: string = "Move to Bench";
  goal;
  players: object = [
    {
      photo: "../../assets/images/lonzo.jpeg",
      name: "Lonzo Ball",
      position: "G",
      moves: 5
```

},

With the code above I want to click a button and move this player to the bench. I'd also like to decrement the amount of moves remaining for each individual player. Below is some of the HTML.

```
<div class="starters">
  <div class=" col color-dark">
    <p>Starters</p>
  </div>

  <div class="player-block" *ngFor="let player of players">
    <div class="player-card">
      <img src="{{ player.photo }}" alt="">
      <p>{{ player.name }} {{ player.position }}</p>
      <p>Moves Remaining: {{moves}}</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <form class="" action="">
        <input *ngIf="moves > 0" (click)="decreaseMoves()" class=" btn btn-sm waves-light" type="submit" value="{{ btnText }}">
      </form>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What structure represents the bench? Is there another property on the component for this?

Comment: Yes. There is another identical component to this one which represents the bench.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to remove an Item from an array, you could use the splice function (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

Your decreaseMoves function should look like that :

```typescript
function decreaseMoves(playerIndex : number) { 
     moves = moves-1
     playerToMove = players.splice(playerIndex, 1);//splice return the removed item.
     bench.insert(playerToMove);
}
```

To pass the index to the function you need to add a variable i binded to the index of the *ngFor statement, like that :

```
*ngFor="let player of players; let i = index"
```

And then call decreaseMoves with i as argument.

```
(click)="decreaseMoves(i)"
```

To work with another component you should declare a Service. 
The Service would have the players set and the bench set and you have to had a function like the decreaseMoves one I presented above that do this for you.

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
      players : Players[] = []
      bench : Players[] = []
      moves : number = 0
      public function MovePlayerToBench(index) {
           moves -= 1
           playerToMove = this.players.splice(playerIndex, 1);//splice return the removed item.
           this.bench.insert(playerToMove);
      }
      public function GetPlayers() : Players[] { 
           return this.players
      }
      public function GetBench() : Players[] { 
           return this.bench
      }
      public function GetMoves() : number { 
           return this.moves
      }
}
```

Comment: Will the "bench.insert(playerToMove)" work given that its in a different component? I was thinking I need to use the service module in order for communication between components.

Comment: Yeah you should use a service. The function will be the same but deported in the service.

Comment: Sry but sounds like I need to do those functions in the service file. I guess all of the functionality happens there and I connect the components.

Answer (score 0):

My function requires you add the player being clicked to the method and have some unique property on each player, such as an id.

```
<input *ngIf="moves > 0" (click)="decreaseMoves(player)" class=" btn btn-sm waves-light" type="submit" value="{{ btnText }}">

decreaseMoves(selectedPlayer: any): void {
    this.players = this.players.filter(player => {
        return player.id !== selectedPlayer.id;
    });
    const playerWithDecrementedMoves = Object.assign(selectedPlayer, {moves: selectedPlayer.moves - 1});
    this.bench.push(playerWithDecrementedMoves);
}
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfleming/qpo6hd1w/9/) with a pure js class example to test the logic.

Comment: Appears this example doesn't use another component for the bench just an array within the same component. What about moving back to the starting lineup from the bench? Appears I can just do the same but in reverse.

Comment: To your last point, yeah if the bench fills up and you want to "reset", you could add those to the players array again.  Sorry, I missed your response to my comment above.  I didn't know where the bench was.  If the component is contained within the RosterBoxComponent partial, you can use input and output bindings.  https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Comment: Appears it would be easier if the button would just work as a toggle to move between the starter and bench array.